# onChange in datepicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using DatePicker from Material UI v0.
For that I have created different component named `DateField` which return DatePicker like this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          onChange={this.onChange}
          maxDate={this.state.maxDate}
          minDate={this.state.minDate}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And for onChange I have done like this:

```
this.onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
```

The function is defined like this:

```
_onChange(p,date){
  this.props.onChange(date);
  this.setState({ value: date });
}
```

Now I am calling this component like this

```
<DateField
  onChange={(date)=>console.log(date)}
>
```

But as soon as I change the date the value of DatePicker does not get updated.

Also when I remove `onChange` prop from `DateField` I get an error that `this.props.onChange` is not a function but the value gets displayed in Date Picker

Could not understand what is the issue

Also when I use `DateField` inside redux form `Field` then it works perfectly as I think in that case the onChange is passed by `Field`

DatePicker: https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker

Comment: maybe a typo? this should be `onChange={this._onChange}`

Comment: @AhsanAli But why?

Answer (score 0):

change your code to :

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          onChange={this.props.onChange} //-- this line add props
          maxDate={this.state.maxDate}
          minDate={this.state.minDate}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: But the previous one should also work. Also when I use `DateField` inside redux form `Field` then it works perfectly as I think in that case the onChange is passed by `Field`